# wma files will not play on 64 bit windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-media-player

My phone company emails me my voicemail as a wma file.  I can open them just fine on my Ubuntu 32-bit netbook using Audacious or in a 32-bit Windows XP virtual machine [running on my Windows 7 64-bit Desktop] using its version of WMP.  But,if I try to open them on my Windows 7 64-bit Desktop I get errors in WMP [missing codec] and VLC [undf aka undedined format].  It is extremely annoying to have to go to another computer, because a Windows media file will not open in Windows Media Player.  Is this a bug in 64-bit WMP or Windows 7?  Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to talk with your phone company and find out what codec they use if you're not very tech savvy on pulling apart the audio file. This is very similar concept to GoToMeeting Recordings where you can plan it on your computer and it's a WMV file, but encoded with a proprietary software encoder.

Ubuntu will play it because you probably checked off the Install Third Party software during the installation process.

Comment: Windows media player in Windows-XP sp3 32-bit works.  So the codec is compatible with WMP it just wont play in Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: They use the sipro lab aclepnet codec which does not come with WMP-12 or Windows-7 nor is it part of the k-lite mega codec pack.  I did find it on the internet and installed it.  Since it was included in past versions of windows and VOIP companies tend to use it.  I am surprised they took it out.

Comment: It can be found at http://www.voiceage.com/acelp_eval.php